# how to get base url in smarty codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

i am trying to use smarty with codeigniter, the thing is i worked with codeigniter but never did worked with smarty, but trying learning it.. :)

right now a little issue is that in codeigniter when i need baseurl i use this

```
<?php echo base_url('styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'); ?>
```

but how to use it using smarty templates, i mean in smarty .tpl files instead of

i did it like this but it didnt worked for me..

```
{base_url('styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');}
```

but got error. i know its not right way but had to try lol..

any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You made little typo on ";"

```
{base_url('styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}
```

### note :

url_helper must be loaded before displaying template

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this I didn't test this

```
{'styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'|base_url}
```

or you can write php code inside template

```
{php}
  $this->assign('my_url',base_url('styles/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'));
{/php}

{$my_url}
```

see this http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl

Answer (score 1):

I have used this function for my controller in form action to redirect to my method it worked .

```
{base_url('my_controller/my_method')}
```